# Is there a list of books where Jesus was witnessed not reflected in The Bible?

Tags: jesus, history

What other religious books or writings contain Jesus not found in the Bible? I understand there maybe many answers so maybe there is a list somewhere of writing documenting Jesus activities? 
Contemporary literature is fine but I am more interested in old documents.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are roughly six sets of documents outside the Bible that are not, strictly speaking, part of the Bible but discuss matters in the Bible, including Jesus.  These consist of:

- The deuterocanonical works, sometimes also called the apocrypha.  All these works, such as the book of Judith were written before the birth of Jesus.  Copies can be easily obtained on-line or in almost any Catholic copy of the Bible.  Protestant Bible do not contain these works.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocrypha for more information.  Within this group are a mixture of fiction (eg, Judith) and historical data (eg Maccabees)
- The so-called Old Testament Pseudepigrapha.  As the name implies, these are all forgeries written by mostly unknown people pretending to be someone famous.  Almost all in this category were written before the birth of Jesus.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Old_Testament_pseudepigrapha
- The New Testament Pseudepigrapha are also forgeries and include numerous works such as the Gospel of Mary, the Gospel of Peter, the Gospel of Thomas, etc.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament_apocrypha  All these works were probably written in the early second century by unknown authors pretending to be someone famous.
- The Nag Hammadi manuscripts - a group of highly gnostic writings from about 100 AD.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nag_Hammadi_library
- Works by secular historians of the first century and early second century.  The most famous among these is Philo Josephus.  But other include works of Tacitus and a few other.  Their mentions of Jesus are mostly in passing and very brief but worth consulting. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sources_for_the_historicity_of_Jesus
- Lastly, some might also include the Qumran documents or "dead sea scrolls" that are not Bible manuscripts.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_Dead_Sea_Scrolls  These all date from about 200 BC to about 100 AD.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should modern religious texts count as yet another group of documents about Jesus? The OP doesn't specify a time period during which the documents should have been authored.

Comment: You are theoretically correct.  I (rashly) assumed Muze was interested in more contemporary books about Jesus.  We might also include the apostolic fathers plus the ante Nicaean father plus many more since.

Comment: @Dr Peter McGowan I was particularly interested in direct witness writing or books that directly reflects Jesus's actions by Direct observation

Comment: All the eye-witness accounts of Jesus are in the Gospels of Matthew, Mark, Luke and John.  Thus far, we have discovered no more genuine eye-witness accounts.  Those of the NT pseudepigrapha are forgeries and most of the Nag Hammadi MSS were written too late.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan what about the book of Judith?

Comment: Arguably, the list of eye-witness accounts contains zero documents. Eye-witness accounts would have been written in the first-person, as the Pauline epistles are. The gospels are written in the third person by anonymous authors who freely crib from each other. There are other indicators that the gospels are not eye-witness accounts, but many are theologically debatable.

Comment: I assumed Acts claims to have eye witness accounts, at least until Acts 1:9? 1:3-9 follows the narrative structure of the canonicals. As opposed to sayings compilations like the hypothesis early Thomas compilation

Comment: Quite right @Samuel Russel, but this is part of the Bible and an extension of the Gospel of Luke.

Comment: @Muse - the book of Judith is part of the deuterocanonical books of the OT, a historical novel (work of fiction) and was written before the birth of Jesus.  It does not mention Jesus.